# Reference request: continuous functions map a convergence sequence to a function of the limit point

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I'm fairly certain this is true but I'm having trouble tracking it down in a book so I'm looking for a reference.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, let $g(x)$ be a map from the Banach space $X$ to $\mathbb{R},$ and let $g({x}_n)$ be a convergent sequence to some point $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}.$

Then I'm fairly sure there are reasonable conditions under which

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(g({x_n}))$ converges to $f(g(x))$ in such a way that
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(g({x_n})) = f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}g({x_n})).$

Mostly I'm just concerned about this for norms and polynomials, like if
$$||x_n|| \rightarrow ||x||,$$ then I'd like to be able to say for instance that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||x_n||^2 = \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}||x_n|| \right)^2.$$

Comment: If $f$ is defined on $X$ then how are you making sense of $f(g(x))$, when $g$ takes values in $\mathbb R$?  Maybe you want $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$ and $g\colon X\to \mathbb R$?

Comment: That's correct, it was a little more messy than I originally imagined in since I'm mainly concerned with just real numbers. Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $g$ map $X$ to $\mathbb{R}.$ Then I'm considering $f(g(x))$ as a map from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: (downgrading this to a comment from an actual answer because I see you were looking for a reference and I don't want to swear to any given book at the moment, though most intro texts should have this.)  Continuity is already exactly the "reasonable condition" you seek (indeed, you only need continuity at the one limit point in question).  That is, for any function $f\colon X\to Y$ between metric spaces, $f$ is continuous at a point $x\in X$ if and only if for every convergent sequence $x_n\to x$ we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.  Continuity in general is then equivalent to continuity at every point.

Comment: +1 to M W's comment that what you are asking for is precisely the definition of continuity of $f$. If for some reason you are using a different definition of continuity for $f$ (like the topological definition), standard texts like Rudin's PMA should show that the definitions are equivalent, or see also [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Continuity_on_Metric_Spaces).

Comment: Everyone keeps saying "standard" or "introductory" texts will show what I'm asking for. Please prove your claims, this is what the question asks for as a reference request.

Comment: @CheeseBlues Theorem 29 in these MIT notes is the result I mentioned. 
 Apologies that I missed this was a reference request earlier. 
 https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-s190-introduction-to-metric-spaces-january-iap-2023/resources/mit18_s190iap23_lec2/   I don't have convenient Library access at the moment so if you're looking for a text reference someone else will have to provide it.

Comment: I've often heard this fact being called "the sequential criterion for continuity"; that might help you look it up too.

Answer (score 1):

Pete L. Clark's [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf) have this result indeed more metric spaces (and much more!). See proposition 2.4.